# How to detect a paired bluetooth device wake up and connected in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I can use `CBCentralManager.retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices:)` to get a list of paired bluetooth devices once. Is there a way to detect the change in this list, i.e. some delegates or notification fire when a paired device turn on and connected? `centralManager(_:didConnect:)` does not fire in this case.
I want to detect a paired HID (remote camera shutter) connection.

Comment: Classic bluetooth or BLE?

Answer (score 0):

How about `centralManager(_:didDiscover:advertisementData:rssi:)`

Comment: Not firing either.

Comment: You can put centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: options) inside didDiscoverPeripheral to keep scanning for bluetooth device

Comment: I have scan running but this is not the problem. The device is already paired and get connected right the way once it wakes up without triggering the scanner.

Comment: did you set your class to delegate = self?

Comment: Yes. I can scan and connect BLE devices, which are not paired on the OS level, with delegates firing normally. My problem is bluetooth HID devices paired on the OS level won't trigger any delegates when wake up. I want to detect that

Answer (score 0):

Register for **EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification** to get notified when bluetooth device get connected.